¿Por que me aparece el siguiente error a la hora de entrar al formulario de mi pagina enviando solicitud ajax?
Espero que estés bien. Estoy trabajando en un sistema de reserva de números para una aplicación web que estoy desarrollando, pero estoy enfrentando algunos problemas.
Tengo un código en JavaScript que intenta reservar un número en la base de datos a través de una solicitud AJAX. Sin embargo, me está dando un mensaje de error que dice "bloqueado: otros" en la consola, lo que creo que podría estar relacionado con problemas de CORS.
Aquí tienes un resumen de lo que tengo:
Estoy haciendo una llamada AJAX para reservar un número. La URL actual que estoy usando es C:/xampp/htdocs/Rifas/private/formulario/process_form.php?action=reservar_numero, lo que creo que puede ser parte del problema.
En el archivo PHP, tengo la lógica para verificar si el número ya está reservado y, si no lo está, lo inserto en la tabla reservas_temporales.
También verifico si el ID de usuario está definido en la sesión, pero no estoy seguro de si se está estableciendo correctamente.
¿Podrías ayudarme a identificar qué podría estar causando este problema y cómo podría solucionarlo? Agradecería cualquier consejo o sugerencia.
   $(document).ready(function() {
            function refrescarNumeros() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'C:/xampp/htdocs/Rifas/private/formulario/process_form.php?action=get_numeros',
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(response) {
                        if (response.success) {
                            $('#numero').empty();
                            $('#numero').append('<option value="">--Selecciona un número--</option>');
                            response.numeros.forEach(function(numero) {
                                $('#numero').append('<option value="' + numero.id + '">' + numero.id + '</option>');
                            });
                        } else {
                            console.error(response.message);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        console.error('Error al obtener los números disponibles.');
                    }
                });
            }   

//y este es el process    
// Lógica de reserva de número
        if (isset($_POST['reservar_numero'])) {
            $numero_id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'numero', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
            
            // Verifica que el ID de usuario esté definido y que el número sea válido
            if ($numero_id && isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
                $usuario_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
        
                // Verifica si el número ya está reservado
                $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM reservas_temporales WHERE numero_id = :numero_id AND reservado_hasta > NOW()");
                $stmt->bindValue(':numero_id', $numero_id);
                $stmt->execute();
        
                if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
                    echo json_encode(['success' => false, 'message' => 'El número ya está reservado.']);
                    exit;
                }
        
                // Inserta en reservas_temporales
                $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO reservas_temporales (numero_id, usuario_id, reservado_hasta) VALUES (:numero_id, :usuario_id, NOW() + INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)");
                $stmt->bindParam(':numero_id', $numero_id);
                $stmt->bindParam(':usuario_id', $usuario_id);
        
                if ($stmt->execute()) {
                    echo json_encode(['success' => true, 'message' => 'Número reservado por 5 minutos.']);
                } else {
                    $errorInfo = $stmt->errorInfo();
                    echo json_encode(['success' => false, 'message' => 'Error al reservar el número: ' . $errorInfo[2]]);
                }
            } else {
                echo json_encode(['success' => false, 'message' => 'ID de usuario no definido.']);
            }introducir el código aquí
            exit;
        }


Probablemente es un tema de cors

Muestra la solicitud AJAX, y el error completo, dentro de la publicación. No podemos estar asumiendo problemas, sin tener las variantes concretas.

Ya lo edite, si me puede ayudar a fondo, les agradecería

En vez de C:/xampp/htdocs/ intenta ponerhttp://localhost. Es decir: http://localhost/Rifas/private/formulario/process_form.php?action=get_numeros Debería funcionar así, si la ruta es correcta y tienes todo bien configurado.
